# Syntax error in expression of SSRS

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I have two datasets in my report and data is being displayed through a table.  When I give expression like below:

```
=Format(Fields!InvDt.Value, "dsRepSalesReport_tblPrintSalesReport","dd/MMMyyyy")
```

It says there is Syntax error.  If I remove

```
dsRepSalesReport_tblPrintSalesReport
```

part, there is no error.

1) Please advise how to wite the expression in format with aggregate expression.

2) If I write expression without

```
dsRepSalesReport_tblPrintSalesReport
```

part, my table repeats data and shows for all invoice.  But when I add aggregate part,

```
dsRepSalesReport_tblPrintSalesReport
```

Table just shows one value several times.

Please advise how to handel with these two issues.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method signature for [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59bz1f0h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is:

```
Public Shared Function Format(
   ByVal Expression As Object,
   Optional ByVal Style As String = ""
) As String
```

So that means you can't just specify the field and the Scope as in your first example; the first of the two arguments must return one value only.

In your example, you could use something like:

```
=Format(First(Fields!InvDt.Value, "dsRepSalesReport_tblPrintSalesReport"), "dd/MMMyyyy")
```

Which will format the first value in the specified Scope.

Another option would be to just set the value as required in the report then use the **Format** property:

[image]

It's difficult to answer your second question without knowing what your data/required results are... If you update the question with some simplified sample data to illustrate the actual issue you're facing that would be helpful.